# how to use awk or sed command (OS level commands) in Sybase level

Tags: unix, sybase

I have one text file in host level Ex: */tmp/file.txt*. So I have one script and I need to read the line by line from *file.txt*, so I used `sed` command. So I am using while loop in the script and I have logged in to DB level, how can I use `sed` command or similar to `sed` for accessing one line data from file.txt ?in database level

Ex: `sed -n '5p' "/tmp/file.txt"   (or) awk 'NR==5' /tmp/file.txt`

So this output I want to check in db level after `isql` command? Is it possible. Can any one suggest the alternate?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the Sybase Adaptive Server's [`xp_cmdshell`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc36273_1251/html/sprocs/X20958.htm):

> **Description**
>
> Executes a native operating system command on the host
>   system running Adaptive Server.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> xp_cmdshell command [, no_output]
> ```

For your commands that would be:

```
xp_cmdshell 'sed -n 5p /tmp/file.txt'

xp_cmdshell 'awk "NR==5" /tmp/file.txt'
```

Be careful with different [quotation](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) types when using quotes inside quotes.

Comment: I have tried that too. It is not working..                                                               1> xp_cmdshell command [ awk 'NR==5' /userids.txt,no_output]
2> go
Msg 102, Level 15, State 181:
Server '', Line 1:
Incorrect syntax near '[ awk 'NR==5' /userids.txt,no_outpu'.                                       Tried for sed also the same syntax error. i have tried exec xp_cmd shell also but no use

Comment: I bet you're supposed to replace 'command' with the actual command:  `xp_cmdshell awk 'NR==5' /userids.txt`

Comment: Exactly! That's only the **syntax**. In that kind of lines `[ ]` indicates that the `, no_output` is optional. The `command` is replaced with the actual command. See the linked manual: it has examples and everything.

Answer (score 0):

Re: So this output I want to check in db level after isql command? Is it possible. Can any one suggest the alternate?

Are you saying:
1) want to process the output of a db level command using shell script syntax? Or,  2) Or take the output of a shell script and send it to be processed in the database?

If 1), there's a alternate to isql called sqsh.  You can do this with sqsh:

```
sqsh -SMYSERVER -Dmydb -Umylogin -w180
<mypassword>
select blah_column from blah_table
go |  sed 's/thingy/widget/g'
```

If 2), then have your shell script produce SQL commands for output and run that against the db using isql -i (or sqsh -i)

Note, if using awk in sqsh, be careful.  Sometimes it needs extra backslashes for the dollar signs